# how to debug an increase in context switches

Tags: performance, linux-kernel, performance-testing, performancecounter, perf

I am profiling two versions of a large application using Linux perf. There is a reproducible degradation of performance in one of the versions. The problem is affecting a run which takes about 10 minutes to complete, and running

```
perf stat
```

one can see that there's a large difference in the number of context switches:

```
    2759681,344820      task-clock (msec)         #    4,089 CPUs utilized          
         1.976.068      context-switches          #    0,716 K/sec                  
           288.370      cpu-migrations            #    0,104 K/sec                  
         1.065.076      page-faults               #    0,386 K/sec                  
 9.600.316.147.196      cycles                    #    3,479 GHz                    
 9.608.308.311.681      instructions              #    1,00  insn per cycle         
 1.847.613.212.847      branches                  #  669,502 M/sec                  
    29.342.163.081      branch-misses             #    1,59% of all branches        

     674,891697479 seconds time elapsed
```

versus

```
    3045676,296012      task-clock (msec)         #    4,093 CPUs utilized          
        22.156.426      context-switches          #    0,007 M/sec                  
           385.364      cpu-migrations            #    0,127 K/sec                  
         1.066.383      page-faults               #    0,350 K/sec                  
10.505.321.454.387      cycles                    #    3,449 GHz                    
 9.723.994.869.100      instructions              #    0,93  insn per cycle         
 1.869.145.049.594      branches                  #  613,704 M/sec                  
    30.241.815.060      branch-misses             #    1,62% of all branches        

     744,170941002 seconds time elapsed
```

Running

```
perf record -e context-switches -ag -T
```

gives the following system calls

```
  Children      Self       Samples  Command          Shared Object                   Symbol 
+   44,06%    44,06%        170846  swapper          [kernel.kallsyms]               [k] schedule_idle 
+   33,07%    33,07%        127004  Thread (pooled)  [kernel.kallsyms]               [k] schedule
```

versus

```
  Children      Self       Samples  Command          Shared Object                 Symbol 
+   49,02%    49,02%        958827  swapper          [kernel.kallsyms]             [k] schedule_idle 
+   43,96%    43,96%        855603  Thread (pooled)  [kernel.kallsyms]             [k] schedule
```

So the difference in the number of samples is almost one order of magnitude. My question is how can I investigate this further, given that I can access the source code of both versions, but it's large and I don't know much about it?

## Update:

The problem was a lock, I can spot it by running gdb, breaking in the middle of the execution, catching the system calls and printing the backtrace

```
(gdb) catch syscall
(gdb) bt
```

The information reported by perf was this

```
  Children      Self  Command          Shared Object                 Symbol                                                                                                                                                                                                              ◆
-   49,02%    49,02%  swapper          [kernel.kallsyms]             [k] schedule_idle                                                                                                                                                                                                   ▒
   - secondary_startup_64                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                ▒
      - 42,82% start_secondary                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                           ▒
           cpu_startup_entry                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                             ▒
           do_idle                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                       ▒
           schedule_idle                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                 ▒
      + 6,20% x86_64_start_kernel


-   43,96%    43,96%  Thread (pooled)  [kernel.kallsyms]             [k] schedule                                                                                                                                                                                                        ▒
   - 43,32% syscall                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                      ▒
      - 43,32% entry_SYSCALL_64_after_hwframe                                                                                                                                                                                                                                            ▒
           do_syscall_64                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                 ▒
           sys_futex                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                     ▒
           do_futex                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                      ▒
           futex_wait                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                    ▒
           futex_wait_queue_me                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                           ▒
           schedule
```

which is not very informative since it does not print who made the system call. Stepping with GDB worked in my case but can be tedious. Do you know any tracing toool, or options to perf which would help in such cases? There's a list of tools on Brendan Gregg's blog http://www.brendangregg.com/blog/2015-07-08/choosing-a-linux-tracer.html , but I haven't much experience with them.

Comment: Does the application do anything that might *require* context switches, like mutexes or condition variables?  (Maybe look for `futex` system calls with `strace`).  Or do you just start more threads in one version, so they can't all be running at once?  Do you get fewer context switches on a machine with more cores?

Comment: Yes it runs with multiple threads using QtConcurrent, and might have mutexes. I'll try with strace tomorrow.

Comment: Both versions have nearly the same CPU utilization, at around 4.1 CPUs on average.  Maybe try with `perf stat -I 100` to sample every 100ms and see if that's consistent or if there are bursts of more or less usage.  Are the diffs between the two versions large, or is it a small change to the large codebase?  I think it's hard to say much from a black-box perspective.  If we had some idea what kind of thing the app was doing, and where its main bottlenecks are, knowing something about what changed could help a lot.